# SVG GRID Transformation - Flip Horizontally

Tags: svg, path, grid

I need to flip this SVG Grid horizontally, because I'd like to drawing the grid from the top left corner, not the bottom left. If run the code, you'll see what's my problem. I need the full squares from the bottom left corner.

Here it is the code:

```
<svg width="80mm" height="50mm" viewBox="0 0 80 50" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> 
<defs><pattern id="grid" width="3" height="3" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"><path  d="M 3 0 L 0 0 0 3" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.3"/></pattern></defs>
<rect x="0" y="0" width="80" height="50" style="fill:gray; stroke-width:0; stroke:black"/><rect x="0" y="0" width="80" height="50" fill="url(#grid)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Your pattern is a 3/3 square. Try making the `viewBox="0 0 90 60"`. Also change the `width` and the `height` of the rects to be múltiple of 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply rotate the whole thing by 180 degrees.

```
<svg width="80mm" height="50mm" viewBox="0 0 80 50" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> 
 <g transform="rotate(180 40 25)">
<defs><pattern id="grid" width="3" height="3" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"><path  d="M 3 0 L 0 0 0 3" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.3"/></pattern></defs>
<rect x="0" y="0" width="80" height="50" style="fill:gray; stroke-width:0; stroke:black"/><rect x="0" y="0" width="80" height="50" fill="url(#grid)"/>
</g>g>
</svg>
```